# Why ‘async1 end’ will log after 'promise2' and 'promise3' in the following script?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Doesn't the microtask of logging 'async1 end' will be push into the queue before the other two?

Why it will be logged after them?

```js
async function async1() {
  console.log('async1 start');
  async2().then(()=>
  console.log('async1 end'));
}

async function async2() {
  console.log('async2 start');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
    console.log('async2 promise');
  })
}

console.log('script start');

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout');
}, 0);

async1();

new Promise(function(resolve) {
  console.log('promise1');
  resolve();
}).then(function() {
  console.log('promise2');
}).then(function() {
  console.log('promise3');
});

console.log('script end');
```

I've found that if i remove the 'async' keyword of async2 and make it a simple function, then it works the same as the way I think.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the delay is that you're **explicitly** returning a promise from an `async` function (`async2`). You don't need to do that, and it introduces an extra async "tick" into the settlement of the promise the `async` function creates implicitly. If you don't make `async2` `async`, you'll see that it does what you expect:

```js
async function async1() {
  console.log('async1 start');
  async2().then(()=>
  console.log('async1 end'));
}

function async2() {
  console.log('async2 start');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
    console.log('async2 promise');
  })
}

console.log('script start');

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout');
}, 0);

async1();

new Promise(function(resolve) {
  console.log('promise1');
  resolve();
}).then(function() {
  console.log('promise2');
}).then(function() {
  console.log('promise3');
});

console.log('script end');
```

Some notes:

- If you don't use `await` in a function, you don't need to make it `async`.
- If you're in an `async` function, you almost never have to use `new Promise`. An `async` function creates a promise implicitly, and settles that promise based on what happens in the function.
- (Again) Returning a *promise* from an `async` function explicitly resolves the implicit promise the `async` function created to the promise you return, introducing an extra tick in the cycle.